# Reset FileReader content in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Good Day,

I want to load a file with the FileReader, then parse its content and convert it to an object. My only problem is everytime I'm loading a file, the object turns out to be always the first one created.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var objID = {};
var myArray = [];

function readBlob() {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    var file = files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        var myString = theFile.target.result;
        myString = myString.split('\n');
        parseTXT(myString);
    });
    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}


function parseTXT(string) {
    for (var index = 0; index < string.length; index += 5) {
        objID.id = data[index];
        objID.refNb = data[index + 2];
        objID.title = data[index + 8];
        objID.isbn = data[index + 15];
    }
    myArray.push(objID);
    console.log(myArray);
}
```

I don't know exactly how to "reset" the file content in order to create an object everytime I'm loading another file. I tried to use this tutorial: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Thanks in advance for the help!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, declare objID variable inside parseTXT function, which we will be used temp object everytime to push to myArray Object

```
function parseTXT(string) {
    var objID = {};
    for (var index = 0; index < string.length; index += 5) {
        objID.id = string[index];
        objID.refNb = string[index + 2];
        objID.title = string[index + 8];
        objID.isbn = string[index + 15];
    }
    myArray.push(objID);
    console.log(myArray);
}
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rdQVLz

Comment: Note sure that works. On your CodePen, a second object replaces the first one. Plus, I'd like to be able to use that array of objects somewhere else in my program. In your example, myArray exists only within the function.

Comment: @EricF, issue is with the objID empty Obj declared as global variable and everytime that global variable changes and thus the myArray changes to first uploaded instead of appending

Comment: updated codepen and my answer , Hope it works for you now :)